# Does Pix attack towers?

Tags: league-of-legends

When you cast "Help, Pix!" and the recipient targets a tower does it add damage or does Pix only attack other units? The description of the skill reads: "If cast on an ally, commands Pix to jump to an ally and shield them. He then follows and aids their attacks."

So, does Lulu's passive (and the associated "Help, Pix!") add damage when attacking structures?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No it does not.

While pix is attached to you, it doesn't help you burn down towers.
While pix is attached to an ally, it doesn't help them burn down towers.

Comment: Yeah found this out the (easy) way today... I simply played and went awww, all that damage my normal attack does is form pix and doesnt work on buildings! heheh :)

Answer (score 2):

A common trend that I noticed is that the tower can only be brought down with physical damage. Towers appear immune to any other types of damage, namely magic and true damage. Of course as we all know, we can't cast spells that deal magic damage on towers. And any on-hit procs that deal magic/true dmg is also negated when using against tower like teemo poison(magic damage), twitch poison(true damage), etc.

The ONLY two exception to this is Rammus's ult which deals magic damage and Alistar passive which also deal magic damage. However in both cases they explicitly explain in the skill description that it will affect buildings.

However, on-hit procs that deal additional physical dmg such as wukong's q does affect tower. Also note that Lichbane also affect tower because it is bonus physical damage.

So since Pix's damage is magic damage, it will not affect the tower in any form regardless who Pix is currently following.

Comment: It is actually on a per champion/per ability basis.
For instance, Twisted Fate's Pick a Card and Ziggs' passive (magic damage) will damage a tower, Renekton's Ruthless Predator and Nocturne's passive (physical) will not.